# Azure Terraform - Use private link between apps in subnetworks

Tags: azure, terraform, endpoint, subnet, azure-rm

I have two web apps: public and private (in different resource groups). I also have two subnets who both belong to the same vnet. The public webapp is linked to the public and the private subnet, the private to a private subnet only. The public subnet and web app have an endpoint as an access point. The private app should be restricted as private (it should have public access blocked and expose a private link). Therefore, the public app should be able to communicate to the private app by the private link.

I use azure portal network troubleshooting to test the connection. The question is, it seems that it still uses the public link, as shown in the screenshot below :

[image: troubleshooting shows not using private link]

For reference, I followed the example in microsoft documentation for my own implementation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/terraform-secure-backend-frontend#the-complete-terraform-file).

and My DNS configuration goes like this :

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "vnetprivateconnection" {
  app_service_id  = azurerm_windows_web_app.webapp_pub.id
  subnet_id       = azurerm_subnet.sbpriv.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "dnsprivatezone" {
  name                = "plpoc.myspace.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_pub.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "dnszonelink" {
  name = "dnszonelink"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_pub.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnsprivatezone.name
  virtual_network_id = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "privateendpoint" {
  name                = "privateendpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_pub.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_pub.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.sbpub.id

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name = "privatednszonegroup"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnsprivatezone.id]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name = "privateendpointconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_windows_web_app.webapp_priv.id
    subresource_names = ["sites"]
    is_manual_connection = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second App service will communicate through a private link. It won't be accessible via public IP, but we can verify the same via a virtual machine.

Replicated the same with below source [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/terraform-secure-backend-frontend#the-complete-terraform-file) reference

main tf file as follows:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "********"
}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "vnet"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "integrationsubnet" {
  name                 = "integrationsubnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  delegation {
    name = "delegation"
    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "endpointsubnet" {
  name                 = "endpointsubnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "swarna-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.endpointsubnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "swarnado-vm"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_NC12s_v3"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "*******!"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "appserviceplan"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  os_type             = "Windows"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "frontwebapp" {
  name                = "webappdemoswarna"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id

  site_config {}
  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER": "168.63.129.16",
    "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL": "1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "vnetintegrationconnection" {
  app_service_id  = azurerm_windows_web_app.frontwebapp.id
  subnet_id       = azurerm_subnet.integrationsubnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "backwebapp" {
  name                = "webappdemoswarna2"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id

  site_config {}
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "dnsprivatezone" {
  name                = "privatelink.azurewebsites.net"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "dnszonelink" {
  name = "dnszonelink"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnsprivatezone.name
  virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "privateendpoint" {
  name                = "backwebappprivateendpoint"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.endpointsubnet.id

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name = "privatednszonegroup"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnsprivatezone.id]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name = "privateendpointconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_windows_web_app.backwebapp.id
    subresource_names = ["sites"]
    is_manual_connection = false
  }
}
```

Upon running here are the service created on portal
[image]

While browse the sites first one will be accessible via public and 2nd one won't be
[image]

[image]

Testing:
Connect VM which are associated with subnet via bastion and browse the 2nd app service URL it will be accessible.

enter below command on powershell prompt we can see the private ip address

```
nslookup <webapp-name>.azurewebsites.net
```

[image]

and able to browse the website inside the VM only.
[image]

NOTE: Port 22 should be open at network level else we will face an VM connectivity issues. Refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-webapp-portal) for more reference about